# How to disable warning "If you restart now, you and any other people using this PC could lose unsaved work"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-11

When I'm trying shutdown or restart my PC, system show me alert "If you restart now, you and any other people using this PC could lose unsaved work":

[image]

I know, this alert also may appear if “Use my sign in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart” option is enabled:

[image]

But I want disable it absolutely. Even if somebody logged in, than locked the session and me need to switch off of restart PC. No any unsaved data no care me. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To disable these massages :

- Run *Settings > Accounts > Sign-in options*
- Scroll down to "Privacy"
- Click to set to Off the option of
  "Use my sign-in info to automatically f‌inish setting up my device
  after an update or restart".

The effect is immediate.

Comment: If this works beyond regular patches and if a user does this., they will be back here asking how to get there file back

Comment: @John: The first message arrives every time that one switches users, meaning if there are multiple user sessions open, no matter if there are open files in the other session or not.

Comment: I think it would be foolish and unprofessional to remove this message. Everyone (and I mean Everyone) will be caught at some time deleting files they needed.  I am not disagreeing with you personally but the warnings are legitimately there for a purpose. BTW.  I fine tuned my own post.

Comment: @John: I don't disagree, just wanted to add some info. It's a bothersome message if one knows what he's doing. For some users it will be useful, while for others not.

Comment: Downvoting my answer because of disagreement with what the poster is requesting is a bit much.

Comment: I don’t why.  You posted a working answer. I don’t agree with removing the warning, but your answer did address how